# Comparing two different types List of Objects

Tags: java

I have two objects of different type but holding similar values. I want to find added  and removed value from the list.
Code  is :

```
List<SelectItem> sourceList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(TypeA);
List<SelectListItems> destinaitonList = new ArrayList<SelectListItems>(TypeB);
```

Both the list contains the same same fields, but of different objects.

```
sourceList.getItemValue();
sourceList.getItemLabel();


destinaitonList.getItemValue();
destinaitonList.getItemLabel();
```

I want to compare the label value and want to know what was added to destination list and what was removed from destination list, when compared to Source List.

Say :

```
SourceList (A, B , D, E)
DestinationList (A, G, H, K )

Result : Added G, H, K
Removed : B, D, E
```

So far I have tried this:

```
List < SelectItem > tempList1 = new ArrayList < SelectItem > ();
List < SelectListItems > tempList2 = new ArrayList < SelectListItems > ();
for (SelectItem s1: sourceList) {
    for (SelectListItems d1: destinaitonList) {
        if (!s1.getItemLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(d1.getItemLabel())) {
            tempList1.add(s1);
        } else {
            tempList2.add(d1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I was trying to compare the value for(SelectItem s1 : sourceList){
  
  for(SelectItem d1 : destinaitonList){
   if(s1.getItemLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(d1.getItemLabel())) {
    tempList1.add(s1);
    
   } else {
    tempList2.add(d1);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question, so we may better help you, instead of giving you a whole solution

Comment: I created two templist and then started comparing values. <br/> List<SelectItem> tempList1 = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
List<SelectListItems> tempList2 = new ArrayList<SelectListItems>();

 for(SelectItem s1 : sourceList){
  
  for(SelectListItems d1 : destinaitonList){
   if(!s1.getItemLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(d1.getItemLabel())) {
    tempList1.add(s1);
    
   } else {
    tempList2.add(d1);
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `contains()` method:

```
ArrayList<Character> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'D', 'E'));
ArrayList<Character> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'G', 'H', 'K'));

ArrayList<Character> added = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Character> removed = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++)
    if (!l1.contains(l2.get(i)))
        added.add(l2.get(i));

for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++)
    if (!l2.contains(l1.get(i)))
        removed.add(l1.get(i));
```

This solution works even if the two lists contain **different type of object**, just use `Arraylist<?>` for the `added` and the `removed` list. Here's an example where I used `ArrayList<?>` for the two start lists:

```
ArrayList<?> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 1, 'B', 2));
ArrayList<?> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 3, 'C', 1));

for (int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++)
    if (l1.contains(l2.get(i)))
        System.out.print(l2.get(i));
```

Output will be: `"A1"`.

If the two lists are **different** and there is **one common field on which to compare**, use two nested loop:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Main
{
    static class A
    {
        private int number;
        private char character;

        public A (int number, char character) {
            this.number = number;
            this.character = character;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public char getCharacter() {
            return character;
        }
    }


    static class B
    {
        private int number;
        private String string;

        public B (int number, String string) {
            this.number = number;
            this.string = string;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<A> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new A(1, 'a'), new A(2, 'b'), new A(3, 'c'), new A(4, 'd')));
        ArrayList<B> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new B(1, "a"), new B(-2, "b"), new B(-3, "c"), new B(4, "d")));

        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < l2.size(); j++)
                if (l1.get(i).getNumber() == l2.get(j).getNumber())
                    // l1.get(i) and l2.get(j) are equals
    }
}
```

Comment: You've changed their whole solution with this code.. `Simply use the contains() method`...

Comment: What's the problem? This response answers the question. If an user write an inefficient piece of code, why shouldn't we show him the right way? Only seeing how other people reach the solution we can increase our skills.

Comment: @austinwernli The list are two different objects                                     List < SelectItem > tempList1 = new ArrayList < SelectItem > ();
List < SelectListItems > tempList2 = new ArrayList < SelectListItems > ();
Since they are two different object, there is one common field on which I want to compare.

Comment: @user2690130 - this code works even if the objects are different. I've just edited my answer to show you how it works.

Comment: @user2690130 - now it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
Set < SelectItem > addedList = new HashSet < SelectItem > ();
Set < SelectListItems > removedList = new HashSet < SelectListItems > ();

for (SelectItem s1: sourceList) {
        if(!destinaitonList.contains(s1)){
            removedList.add(s1)
        }
   }
}
 for (SelectListItems d1: destinaitonList) {
        if(!sourceList.contains(d1)){
            addedList.add(d1);
        }
}
```

to accomodate your design problems you can do something like (Have changed the order of for loops in one case)

```
for(int j=0; i < sourceList.size(); i++) {
    for(int i=0; i< destinationList.size(); i++){ 
        boolean found=false;
            if(sourceList.get(j).getItemValue().equals(destinaitonList.get(i).getItemVa‌​lue()))
                found=true;
        if(!found){
            System.out.println(sourceList.get(j).getItemValue()+" not found in destination list so it is removed")
        }   
    }
}

for(int i=0; i< destinationList.size(); i++){ 
    for(int j=0; i < sourceList.size(); i++) {
        boolean found=false;
            if(destinaitonList.get(i).getItemVa‌​lue().equals(sourceList.get(j).getItemValue()))
                found=true;
        if(!found){
            System.out.println(destinaitonList.get(i).getItemVa‌​lue()+" not found in source list list so it is added")
        }   
    }
}
```

This will do it, after it works successfully try and do it in one double for loop, kind of homework for you :)

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks all for the response, but now I have been investigating more into the issue and found that the "destinaitonList.contains(s1)" always returns false, even if has same value. I did an equals on it and it returns false. I am guessing when my two list objects are different, the framework is considering it as whole new instance. I am not sure, if I am putting it correct but I see these are considered as two seperate objects and contains does not seem to work correctly,

Comment: try to ovverride equals and hashcode method for your Class, whose object you are comparing, and in equals method let your deciding factor be the variable on which you want your removed and added list(i.e A,B etc) , then contains will return a true

Comment: Sorry, If I am getting too messy here. I tried overriding equals and hascode method, but it does not allow me to do so. Because the Select Item and SelectItemsList are encapsulated and I cant modify them. I have to find a solution from java loop, over the list values. This is what my lead told me about the framework.

Comment: Hello, Continuing to my yesterday's logic. I am actually unable to derive a logic where I can find added and removed value from the two lists. I tried the below code for(int i=0; i< destinaitonList.size(); i++){
  for(int j=0; i < sourceList.size(); i++) {
    if(!sourceList.get(j).getItemValue().equals(destinaitonList.get(i).getItemValue())){
     tempList1.add(destinaitonList.get(i));
     System.out.println(destinaitonList.get(j).getItemLabel() + "Added Item to List");
     break;
    } 
    destinaitonList.remove(i);
   }
  } This always gives me wrong. Can u tell where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thi is what I did and it worked smooth for add and delete. List<String> sourList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sourList.add("BANK");
        sourList.add("BENE");
        sourList.add("ADVICE");

        List<String> destList = new ArrayList<String>();
        destList.add("BANK");
        destList.add("ADVICE");
        destList.add("ROLL");
        destList.add("MOBILE");

        for(String sList : sourList){
            boolean present = false;
            for(String dList : destList){
                if(sList.equalsIgnoreCase(dList)){
                    present = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!present)
                System.out.println(sList);          
        }


    }
```